# azure blob pricing with frequent blob update

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I intend to put around 10M of blobs in my azure storage.

A file size is around 100KB.

Every hour I want add a around 100 bytes to each file at a specific location (using seek).

I see from the azure pricing:

Put Blob/Block, List, Create Container Operations
(per 10,000) - 0.1$

All other operations except Delete, which is free
(per 10,000) - 0.01$

(taken from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/)

my question is: All other operations except... Do i need to pay also for the read from blob/ close blob / seek operations ? are they consider as an operation ?

Comment: 1st - you should look at standard storage accounts, not blob-specific. 2nd: all pricing is fully detailed for those storage account types. 3rd: Any REST operation is considered a transaction (aside from specific failure cases; all documented). 4th: the only optimized blob type for your targeted operation is "append blob". But still, not really designed for 100-byte additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All other operations except... Do i need to pay also for the read from blob/ close blob / seek operations ? are they consider as an operation ?

As far as I know, all the operation is regards as REST API operation in the azure.

Read from blob:  Using the Get method to get the file from the blob it consider as all other operations except delete.
The price of the All other operations except delete is $0.05 (LRS Cold per 10,000).

Close blob: Do you mean delete the blob ? If you want to delete blob, it is free.

Seek blob: If you want to seek the blob, you need to use the list blob method, this is regards as Put Blob/Block, List, Create Container Operations.
The price of the Put Blob/Block, List, Create Container Operations is $0.10(LRS Cold per 10,000).